# projAB onto d vs projBA onto d

Tags: vectors

Is the the projection of AB onto a direction vector d the same as the pAB onto a direction vector d? 
What exactly determine the direction of the projection vector??

Thank you

Comment: $\vec{AB}=-\vec{BA}$. So, their corresponding projections on $\vec{d}$ are different. BTW, projection is scalar quantity

Comment: Is it generally good practive to start at the bottom of the vector AB to obtain a projection  that has a same sign scalar as our vector AB? http://imgur.com/cLhTHsb